# OpenCV with FFMPEG back-end and h264_v4l2m2m codec

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, h.264, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to configure OpenCV 4.5.4 that uses FFMPEG back-end to write video file (via `VideoWriter`) with `h264_v4l2m2m` codec instead of `h264`. The difference between those 2 codecs on ffmpeg side is that `h264_v4l2m2m` uses hardware support to encode frames into video file.

If using ffmpeg tool directly via command line (Linux), the codec can be chosen with `-vcodec` argument, however, I don't see a way to accomplish the same in OpenCV and it seems to me that it just uses `h264`.

I notice that by means of CPU usage. `h264` codec uses all cores of CPU, while `h264_v4l2m2m` takes just a little amount of CPU resources due to offloading encoding operations to hardware.

Thus, ffmpeg by itself works fine. The question is: How to achieve the same via OpenCV?

**EDIT** (Feb 2022): At this point of time this is not supported / tested on RPI4 as stated by the dev team in this [comment](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21155#issuecomment-1042919739).

Comment: No can do. OpenCV implements its FFmpeg video I/O with rudimentary use of the FFmpeg libraries. [This C++ class member function](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L2457) directly relates to your need. Take a look.

Comment: @kesh, I've seen that. The only idea that comes to my mind is OPENCV_FFMPEG_WRITER_OPTIONS env. variable usage, however, it does not work if I set it to "vcodec;h264_v4l2m2m"

Comment: related: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21155#issuecomment-1042320318